# How to add corresponding author in acmart class

Tags: latex

I want "Corresponding author" to appear only where Authors’ address are mentioned [bottom of page]. It should not appear at the start [as shown in highlighted image].
I dont want to use \thanks or footnotes. I try authornote at differnt places but it appears separately.
The MWE is as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[acmlarge, authorversion]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

\acmJournal{CSUR}
\acmVolume{}
\acmNumber{}
\acmArticle{}
\acmMonth{3}

\begin{document}
   
\title{Title is ACM}
  
\author{First}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University}
  \city{city}
  \country{country}}
\email{author@author.com}
\author{A}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University}
  \city{city}
  \country{country}}
\email{author@author.com}
\author{B}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University}
  \city{city}
  \country{country}}
\email{author@author.com}
\author{C}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{(corresponding author), University}
  \city{city}
  \country{country}
   }
\email{author@author.com}
% \thanks{(corresponding author)}
%  \authornote{(corresponding author)}
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{author et al.}

\begin{abstract}
abstract here...
\end{abstract}


\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
  <concept>
      <concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002945</concept_id>
      <concept_desc>General and reference~Surveys and overviews</concept_desc>
      <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
      </concept>
  <concept>
      <concept_id>10002978.10003006.10003013</concept_id>
      <concept_desc>Security and privacy~Distributed systems security</concept_desc>
      <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
      </concept>
 </ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Surveys and overviews}
\ccsdesc[300]{Security and privacy~Distributed systems security}
 \keywords{ABC, XYZ}
 \maketitle

\end{document}
\endinput
```